# SQL Server 2016 running on compatibility mode 2008

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have any experience with running SQL Server 2016 on compatibility mode 2008 in terms of performance/ query plans and also general compatibility with 3rd party applications? It will be reassuring if not much changes on the new database.

We are planning the migration of a high volume, few terabytes of data 2008 based system to 2016. We are hoping that performance stay the same (at least).

We will eventually migrate to 2016 compatibility level but not at this stage. Any other advise you can give?

Thanks very much.

Panos.

Comment: This will be better asked on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), however, suffice to say that there have been **significant** changes to SQL Server since 2008. One of the biggest is a completely new cardinality estimation process, which can have huge impacts on performance (both good and bad, depending on how well/poorly your SQL is written and database is designed).

Comment: The only thing you can realistically do is test. One person's experience will say very little about what you can expect -- could be better, could be worse, this will depend greatly on the database. Despite 2016 supporting a compatibility level for 2008, the engine and the optimizer are still considerably different, so expecting the same performance (or only improvements for all queries) is not realistic. With regards to app compatibility you're better off: TDS is highly backwards compatible, and anything that successfully runs now will almost certainly run successfully later.